# How to attach a component in a specific line of GtkBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I created a `GtkBox` with Glade, I added some components at the beginning and end of the `GtkBox` and left a empty line in the middle.
Now, how do I add a new component in the empty line through code? E.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

How do I add a component in position one of the `GtkBox`, through code?

**EDIT:**
Apparently `GtkBox` does not have a method, like [attach](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Grid.html#Gtk.Grid.attach) of `GtkGrid`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you did, what part did not work? Can you show the code? It's quite difficult to answer open-ended questions of type "how do I do X" without an idea what you have already solved ...

Comment: I have not tried anything because according to my [research](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Box.html#methods), `GtkBox` does not have a method where you can inform the desired position.
`GtkGrid` has the [attach method](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Grid.html#Gtk.Grid.attach), but `GtkBox` seems that does not have something similar.
`GtkGrid` seems to be more flexible to choose positions, but I do not need columns just lines, so I think that `GtkBox` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem:

1. Containers store their children's packing properties (stuff like `expand` and `fill` and, you guessed it, `position`). You can use `container_widget.child_set_property(child_widget, 'position', index)` to change the position of a child widget.
2. Use a Grid instead of a Box. You can choose where to add a child widget if you use the `grid.attach` method, or add widgets as if it were a Box (because both inherit from GtkContainer).
3. Instead of leaving the spot empty, insert another (invisible) container widget. This way you can easily add child widgets, and without needing to hard-code their position in the box.